# instanciate an audio file object

Tags: javascript, file, audio, load

instead of this code which works fine

```
<input type="file" id="my_file">

<script>
var file = document.getElementById('my_file').files[0],
reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
//...
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
</script>
```

I would like to instantiate an object to play an mp3 audio file

```
<script>
// for example the following or whatever to pass a file object to readAsArrayBuffer()
var file = new File("./fichier.mp3");       // don't work

reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
//...
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
</script>
```

thanks for your answers

Comment: try new Audio('./fichier.mp3') isntad of file

Answer (score 0):

`var file = new File("./fichier.mp3")` ❌

**First of all, the above line is very wrong. did you read the mdn documentation?**

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

#### File()

The File() constructor creates a new File object instance.

#### Syntax

new File(bits, name)

new File(bits, name, options)

e.g.

```
const file = new File(["foo"], "foo.txt", {
  type: "text/plain",
});
```

Now, first you need to create an audio blob file using `fetch` api.

##### Creating audio blob file and pass it to `callback` function

```
fetch("./fichier.mp3").then(r => r.blob).then(d => callback(d))
```

##### read the arraybuffer

```
function callback(data) {
    console.log(d.arraybuffer())
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert for that - can you show me the complete code with my code above thanks